# User has no profile

Tags: django

This is my first question on this website,if there is something in a wrong way,please excuse me.And if there are some more specific to show,please contact me,thanks.I just run my Django program,and there is something wrong.I have searched it for a long time, but I can not fix it.When I trun to the detail page,the wrong occurs.

[image]
[Enlarge image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iW756.png)

**models.py**

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    belong_to = models.OneToOneField(to=User, related_name='profile',on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    profile_image = models.FileField(upload_to='profile_image')
```

**view.py**

```
def detail(request, id):
    context = {}
    vid_info = Video.objects.get(id=id)
    voter_id = request.user.profile.id
    like_counts = Ticket.objects.filter(choice='like', video_id=id).count()
    try:
        user_ticket_for_this_video = Ticket.objects.get(voter_id=voter_id, video_id=id)
        context['user_ticket'] = user_ticket_for_this_video
    except:
        pass
    context['vid_info'] = vid_info
    context['like_counts'] = like_counts
    return render(request, 'detail.html', context)
```

Comment: the issue comes from this line `voter_id = request.user.profile.id` the current user doesn't have any UserProfile instance attached to it, try to add a UserProfile to `request.user`

Comment: so could you tell me how to create a profile instance attached to it?

Comment: before that, can you tell me how you deal with the model `UserProfile`, how do you create a `UserProfile`? and where you do so in the views..